# Comparison between two strings is not working in shell script

Tags: bash

This piece of code assign the output of the `lsb_release -i` command at the `linux_distro` variable and the script compares it against the first item of `distributor_id` array and then the second and so on. The first item of the array is `"Distributor ID: Arch"` and I am using arch so the `linux_distro` variable is supposed to be equal with the item of the array. Of course since I am posting here this does not seem to be the case.

```
if [ "$linux_distro" = "${distributor_id[0]}" ] || [ "$linux_distro" = "${distributor_id[1]}" ]; then 
    #checking if the yay AUR helper is available (it will be needed for some of the software installed)
    if ! command -v snap > /dev/null; then 
        echo "yay command was not found. Please install the yay AUR helper aur.archlinux.org/packages/yay from and try running the script again."
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

I tried printing out the variable values using `echo` that proved to me that everything is supposed to work as intended and I tried using the `[[` command with the `==` operator, still no solution.

It is to be noted that I replaced yay with snap just because I got yay installed and not snap, so please don't bother with that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can source `/etc/os-release`

```bash
. /etc/os-release

if [ "$ID" = "${distributor_id[0]}" ] || [ "$ID" = "${distributor_id[1]}" ]; then 
    #checking if the yay AUR helper is available (it will be needed for some of the software installed)
    if ! command -v snap > /dev/null; then 
        echo "yay command was not found. Please install the yay AUR helper aur.archlinux.org/packages/yay from and try running the script again."
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

this file is not exists on all linux distro

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any syntax error in your code. As a result, I guess the two string are not really equal to each other. On my system, the result of `lsb_release -i` is separated by a tab ('\t'). Maybe your other string is separated by a space.

Also, as a suggestion, you can source `/etc/os-release` file in your script. Then you can simply compare the value of `$ID` variable for determining the distribution.

Comment: Is /etc/os-release on the /etc directory in every major distribution or not, because I am trying to support as many distributions out there I can.

Comment: I am not a linux distro expert, but I have seen it on major distribution that I have used. Here is a link for the manual https://www.linux.org/docs/man5/os-release.html.